# How to make sure preloader covers entire height and there is no loading page element visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make sure preloader covers entire height and there is no loading page element visible?

> When i run this code the content inside  is visible
>   when i scroll down. How do i make sure the preloader bg covers the
>   entire page ?

html:

```
<div class="pre-outer">
    <div class="preloader">

    </div>
  </div>
<section class="home-section-background padding-bottom-0">
</section>
```

css:

```
/*loader styles */
    .pre-outer
    {
      background: rgba(1,1,1,1);
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 999;
              height: 100%!important;
    }
    .preloader {
       display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
          -ms-flex-pack: center;
              justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
          -ms-flex-align: center;
              align-items: center;

      overflow: hidden;
      background: rgba(1,1,1,1);
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
              z-index: 999;
              height: 100%!important;
      -webkit-animation: glow 8s both;
              animation: glow 8s both;

    }
```

javascript code for loader:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function () {


            $('.pre-outer').delay(8000).fadeOut('slow');//loader div

        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to cover the total height of the content. Just set the position of preloader to fixed instead of absolute;

```
position: fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
height:100%;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `position: absolute` to `position: fixed` and it will continue to overlay the screen even if you scroll:

```
/*loader styles */
    .pre-outer
    {
      background: rgba(1,1,1,1);
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 999;
              height: 100%!important;
    }
    .preloader {
       display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
          -ms-flex-pack: center;
              justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
          -ms-flex-align: center;
              align-items: center;

      overflow: hidden;
      background: rgba(1,1,1,1);
      width: 100%;
      position: fixed;
              z-index: 999;
              height: 100%!important;
      -webkit-animation: glow 8s both;
              animation: glow 8s both;

    }
```

If you want to disable scrolling completely during the preload screen, you'd have to set an overflow hidden and a height on your body element and then remove this after the preloader closes, but that will result in a slight jump in the content as the scrolbar suddenly appears.